# Fail to pass array address by copy to anonymous function

Tags: c++, c++11

```
void F(int A[], int n) { // Correct
    int arr[3] = {0}; // A[..] in the range of 0-2
    for_each(A, A+n, [&arr](const int& num) -> void {
       ++arr[num];
    });
}

void F(int A[], int n) { // Wrong: b/c [arr] should be [&arr]
    int arr[3] = {0}; // A[..] in the range of 0-2
    for_each(A, A+n, [arr](const int& num) -> void {
       ++arr[num];
    });
}
```

> error: increment of read-only location ‘arr[((int)num)]’ ++arr[num];

Question> Why I see the above error?
The parameter in `[]` should be prefixed with `&` if the anonymous function requires to modify the value. However, here, I pass in an address of array. Why I still have to use `[&arr]` instead of `[arr]`.

Thank you

Comment: BTW, your function signature is actually `void F(int* A, int n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are not pointers. `arr` is not a pointer, it's an array. Nowhere does the standard say that array-to-pointer conversions happen on lambda captures. So the lambda is not capturing a pointer, it's capturing the actual array, by value or by reference. And as by-value captures are effectively `const` unless the lambda is declared `mutable`, you're getting the error.

In other words, the closure type of the lambda will have this data member in the `[&arr]` case:

```
int (&arr)[3];
```

And this data member in the `[arr]` case:

```
int arr[3];
```

Do not forget that when the lambda is declared without `mutable`, the closure's `operator()` is a `const` member function:

```
auto operator() (const int& num) const -> void {
  // ... code
}
```

Which means it cannot modify data members captured by value.

Comment: This may all be; but shouldn't in both cases ++arr[num] compile?

Comment: Only within the lambda body, which is `void operator()( const int& num )` ** `const` ** `{ ++arr[num]; }`.  In C++11.

Answer (score 1):

The lambda captures arr as a **const**. If you want to be able to modify the array you need to use **mutable**:

```
void F(int A[], int n) { // Wrong: b/c [arr] should be [&arr]
    int arr[3] = {0}; // A[..] in the range of 0-2
    for_each(A, A+n,  [arr](const int& num) mutable -> void {
       ++arr[num];
    });
}
```

Or, more accurately, the lambda expression is like a const function without the **mutable** keyword:

> 5.1.2.5 The closure type for a lambda-expression has a public inline function
>   call operator (13.5.4) whose parameters and return type are
>   described by the lambda-expression’s parameter-declaration-clause and
>   trailing-return-type respectively. This function call operator is
>   declared const (9.3.1) if and only if the lambda- expression’s
>   parameter-declaration-clause is not followed by mutable.

Comment: Although this might change in C++14